# What's the difference between :w and :sav in spacemacs?

Tags: evil, spacemacs

I'm using spacemacs and while when I create a new buffer with a given name and try to save it into a real file I find that `:w` won't work but `:sav` will. What is the difference between those two commands ?

Comment: Just an additional comment that I like the provided spacemacs bindings "space f s" and "space f c" for saving the file and copying to a file, respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:w` and `:sav` are Evil ex-commands, provided by [Evil](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/wiki/Home). The "bindings" of ex-commands are stored in the variable `evil-ex-commands`, which is an [alist](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html). To examine the variable, run the command `C-h v evil-ex-commands` (in Spacemacs you can use `SPC h d v evil-ex-commands` instead). The output would be something like this:

```
evil-ex-commands is a variable defined in ‘evil-vars.el’.
Its value is shown below.

This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Documentation:
Association list of command bindings and functions.

Value: (("edit" . evil-edit)
        ("e" . "edit")
        ("write" . evil-write)
        ("w" . "write")
        ("wall" . evil-write-all)
        ("wa" . "wall")
        ("saveas" . evil-save)
        ("sav" . "saveas")
        ("read" . evil-read)
        ("r" . "read")
--- I trimmed the rest (the list continues) ---
```

When invoking `:<key>`, Evil looks for `<key>` in `evil-ex-commands` and invokes the corresponding command. As you can see, ":w" is a shortcut for ":write", and ":write" invokes the function `evil-write`. Similarly, ":sav" is a shortcut for ":saveas", which invokes `evil-save`.

To find the differences between `evil-write` and `evil-save`, you can read their documentation by calling `C-h f` or `SPC h d f` (as db48x wrote). It seems that ":w" saves to current file, while ":sav" lets you save to a new file.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use spacemacs, but emacs in general is self-documenting; you can always query the help system for information about keybindings, functions, variables, etc. The normal emacs keyboard shortcut for getting help with a key binding is `C-h k`. From a quick glance at the spacemacs manual (http://spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#orgheadline91), it looks like you should use `SPC h d k`, or possibly `SPC h d f` (I'm not sure if the ex-commands like :w are classified as keyboard shortcuts or functions; probably the former but it might be the latter.)

You should be able to figure out the differnce by comparing the documentation for the two.